# My front dérailleur doesn't shift into the big ring neither in the small one. If I pull the shifter nothing happens

Tags: shifting, cable, derailleur-front

I have a Shimano Sora groupset and my bike is 1 year old. I already tried everything with the limit screws and the cable tension but now nothing moves when I pull the shifter.

I'm not sure how to identify the problem and I don't know how to find out if the cable is broken.

Comment: My first suspicion would be that the cable is either stuck or is too loose.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set up the derailleur from scratch.

Unscrew the cable clamping bolt to disconnect the cable. If you cannot move the derailleur when the cable is disconnected, the problem is there. If the disconnected cable does not move when you move your shifter, the problem is in the shifter. Check that you can move the derailleur all the way in and out.

If the checks are OK: Connect the cable back with such a tension that the chain on the small chainring is in the middle of the derailleur cage. Then set the limit screws according to common tutorials. There are many tutorials on Youtube and elsewhere. Just search for setting up front derailleur.

Comment: First of all thank you for helping me out so much. I can move the deraillieur but the câble dos not reacte  when i move the shifter. So the Problem is in the Shifter but how do i solve it now . Do i need i New shifter or a New cable ?

Comment: @Jeremias You need to disassemble it even more. It is a topic for a new question with photos and everything. I assume you have road drop bar STI shifters. Remove the rubber cover and look inside. Does the cable head move? A problem with the shifter is more likely.  But 100% buy a new cable as well, it is worth it and not expensive.

Comment: As recommended by Argenti Apparatus check also the cable housing. You probably also have a small barrel adjuster somewhere in the middle. Check that it is not disconnected. The cable could also be stuck in the housing. Are you able to pull the old cable out smoothly?

Comment: Last warning, if your bike is just one year old, it may still be covered by the warranty. Check your documents for the bike and if it is, do not do anything mor yourself, not even the new cable. Just bring it to the bikeshop and claim the warranty problem.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Vladimir's answer, trace the route of the cable from the shifter to the derailleur, making sure the sections of housing are inserted into the shifter and frame stops. If a section of housing has come loose the  cable will not be able to pull the derailleur.

If you have exposed cable (likely along the down tube) then you will also be able to see if the cable is moving in response to the shifter.

If the cable is not moving in response to the shifter a possibility is that the end of the cable has become separated in the shifter.

When you find the problem and fix what ever has broken, you'll definitely need to re-adjust the derailleur as you messed with the limit and indexing adjustment. Follow the Park Tool procedure Vladimir linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Does the cable move when you pull the shifter?

If not and you have cable tension, i.e. the cable isn't flopping around, and you shift and nothing moves, then the problem is likely your shifter. The internal gears are usually plastic and can break.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. No even when i have cable tention an pull the shifter the cable doesnt repsond or just 1or 2 mm of movement.  I will replace the cable and see if that helps but im still not sure how to find out if the shifter  has a problem.